# Limit of absolutely continuous functions

Tags: functional-analysis, integration

Is $AC[a,b]$ a closed subspace of $C[a,b]$. If so how does one go about proving this, and if not why? (The proof that it is a subspace is clear)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: For which topology?

Comment: Also, as a counterexample, the Cantor function is a uniform limit of AC functions, but clearly not AC itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $f(x) = \begin{cases} x \sin \frac{1}{x} & x \neq 0 \\ 0 & x=0 \end{cases}$. Then let $f_n(x) = \begin{cases} x \sin \frac{1}{x} & |x| > \frac{1}{n}  \\ x f(\frac{1}{n}) & |x| \leq \frac{1}{n} \end{cases}$. Then $f_n \to f$ uniformly, and $f_n$ is absolutely continuous (since Lipschitz), but $f$ is not absolutely continuous.

Comment: I am not able to see why the convergence is uniform. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x*sin%281%2Fx%29 - the oscillation around origin suggests the convergence is not uniform, or am i mistaken?

Comment: The only place they differ is on $|x| \le \frac{1}{n}$, and the difference is bounded by $2x$ there, hence we have $\sup_x |f(x)-f_n(x)| \leq \frac{2}{n}$.